# How do I sort an array of numbers with an unknown size, using pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

This is the code I have come up so far. This may not be the best way to scan in an array separated by spaces. So what I need to do is sort the in putted array into ascending order and print it. Hopefully somebody can help me out!

```
int main()

char vect1[25];
char *num1;


//First Vector
printf("Enter first Vector seperated by spaces\n");
fgets(vect1, 25, stdin);
printf("The unsorted vector is:\n");

double v1[25];
int count1=0;
num1 = strtok(vect1, " ");

while (num1 != NULL)
{
    sscanf(num1, "%lf", &v1[count1]);
    printf("%.2f\n", v1[count1]); 
    num1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    count1++;
}

printf("Size of Array= %d\n\n", count1);
```

Output is:

```
Enter first Vector separated by spaces
```

User inputs vector (eg. 5 4 9 3 8 2 1)

```
5
4
9
3
8
2
1

size of array= 7
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You don't know how to use pointers, how to sort or what, bro?

Comment: Did you check [`qsort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/)?

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort, easy and fast enough for small arrays.

```
int main()

char vect1[25];
char *num1;
char swap;

//First Vector
printf("Enter first Vector seperated by spaces\n");
fgets(vect1, 25, stdin);
printf("The unsorted vector is:\n");

double v1[25];
int count1=0;
num1 = strtok(vect1, " ");

while (num1 != NULL)
{
    sscanf(num1, "%lf", &v1[count1]);
    printf("%.2f\n", v1[count1]); 
    num1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    count1++;
}
  for (int c = 0 ; c < ( count1 - 1 ); c++)
  {
    for (int d = 0 ; d <  - c - 1; d++)
    {
      if (array[d] > array[d+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
      {
        swap       = array[d];
        array[d]   = array[d+1];
        array[d+1] = swap;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you heaps, this is what I was looking for! Life saver! I had found a solution like this but wasn't able to implement it into my own code, Thankyou!

Comment: You can view more sorting algorithms here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with the added quicksort() function I wrote that will return a sorted array for you. I just chose quicksort because I like it, but any sorting algorithm could be used.

I've added all pertinent functions to get quicksort working, and I've added all their function prototypes above main(). I've also added a print_array function that prints the elements in the array in the same format that you were printing them.

Also, I added the line

```
#define VECSIZE 25
```

after the include statements at the top of the file. You were using the value 25 a lot as a constant, so if you ever wanted to change the value to another number, you would have had to change it in many different spots. Now, if you want to change the size of the vector, all you have to do is change the value of VECSIZE.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define VECSIZE 25 

/* function prototypes */
void quicksort(double *vector, int low, int high);
int partition(double *vector, int low, int high);
void swap(double *array, int i, int j);
void print_array(double *array, int size);

int main() {

  char vect1[VECSIZE];
  char *num1;


  //First Vector
  printf("Enter first Vector seperated by spaces\n");
  fgets(vect1, VECSIZE, stdin);

  double v1[VECSIZE];
  int count1=0;
  num1 = strtok(vect1, " ");

  while (num1 != NULL)
  {
    sscanf(num1, "%lf", &v1[count1]);
    num1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    count1++;
  }

  printf("The unsorted vector is: \n");
  print_array(v1, count1);
  printf("Size of Array= %d\n\n", count1);

  quicksort(v1, 0, count1-1); // count1-1 is the index of the last  element in the array 
  printf("The sorted vector is: \n");
  print_array(v1, count1);
}

void print_array(double *array, int size){
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    printf("%.2f\n", array[i]); 
  printf("\n");
}

/*
  x and y are indices into the array, and the values
  at those indexs will be swapped
*/
void swap(double *array, int x, int y) {
  int placeholder = array[x];
  array[x] = array[y];
  array[y] = placeholder;
}

/*
  Sorts a single element in the array and returns its
  sorted index.
 */
int partition(double *array, int low, int high) {
  int i = low-1;
  int j = low;
  double pivot = array[high];  
  for (j; j < high; j++) {
    if (array[j] <= pivot) {
      i++;
      swap(array, i, j);
    }
  }
  i++;
  swap(array, i, high);
  return i;
}

/*
  recursively sorts an array by sorting the values in the
  array that are left of 'mid' and then sorting the values
  that are greater than 'mid'. The brains of this sorting 
  algorithm is in the partition function.
 */
void quicksort(double *array, int low, int high) {
  int mid;
  if (low < high) {
    mid = partition(array, low, high);
    quicksort(array, low, mid-1);
    quicksort(array, mid+1, high);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also use the predefined qsort function from stdlib instead of writing quicksort on your own.